# Using form validation

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS app where I require users to input their username without special characters.

I need assistance creating a function to validate a text field to accept only letters, numbers, and underscore. And when implement it into the signup Button action, I want to call the function and add an if case for the validation.

Can someone tell me what to do? I have tried other methods online but they seem to be outdated and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Create NSCharacterSet containing alphanumerics and an underscore, like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767675/nscharacterset-how-do-i-add-to-alphanumericcharacterset-text-restriction Then, for each character call `myCharacterSet.characterIsMember(myChar)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933193/swift-ios-alpha-numeric-regex-that-allows-underscores-and-dashes

Comment: *"I have tried other methods online"* what did you try? – *"but they seem to be outdated"* why? Examples?  – *"nothing worked for me"* is a useless description. How did it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this.

You just want a string full of letters, number and underscores and nothing else, so this regex will suffice:

```
^[\w]+$
```

You can write in code like this:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[\\w]+$", options: [])
if regex.firstMatch(in: yourTextField.text!, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: yourTextField.text!.characters.count)) != nil {
    // the string is valid
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much.  how do i limit the characters to a minimum of 5 to a max of 10 ?

Comment: @KingJulian replace the `+` with `{5,10}`

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkUsername(str: String) -> Bool
{
    do
{
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[0-9a-zA-Z\\_]{7,18}$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
    if regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)).count > 0 {return true}
    }
catch {}
return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0**, try this

function validation(strValue : String)-> Bool{

```
let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"^[0-9a-zA-Z\\_]{7,18}$").inverted
    let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
    let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")
    return string == numberFiltered

}
```